# javascript error form validation: all inputs fields are cleared on submitting

Tags: javascript

am using a form to register the user on my website and i have a captcha security on it. Everything is working well and good but the only problem that i am facing is that if i enter a wrong captcha or somehow the page refreshes , all the data entered by the user is wiped out.

what i wish to achieve is that even if the captcha entered is wrong and the form is submitted , the form should have all the fields intact as the user filled in excluding the captcha field.

How can this be done? My form is html and by using javascript im validating it

Comment: Can you post some code that shows how your captcha validation is being called? If it's bound to the submit event most likely you just have to `preventDefault()` if the captcha is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may be smart enough to do this, but if you want to make sure, the only way to retain data across a page reload/refresh (including form submission) is to keep it on the server, and/or put it in a cookie.

However, instead of using a `submit` button, you could use a normal button with an `onclick()` function which validates the data first, then manually submits the form if appropriate.

```
document.forms["form_name"].submit()
```

You also have to handle key events for the form text inputs, to prevent **enter** from submitting. 
However, this is still much easier in the end, since it prevents the page from changing and doesn't require server side storage or cookies.